# Thread sequencing with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice

I have a simple program for two threads to print, incremental numbers, alternately.

So, 
first thread prints : 1

Second thread prints : 2

first thread prints : 3... and so on

I am able to use 'Thread' class to do this. But I want to see how to use Executor class to do this.

With the following code .... executor class does NOT seem to work. Any pointers ??

Code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LocksPackagePractice {

    private int i = 0;

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();  

    Runnable r = () -> {
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        printValue();
    }
    printValue(); 
};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new LocksPackagePractice().trigger();
    }

    void trigger(){
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        service.execute(r);
    }

    void printValue(){

        lock.lock();

        try {

            i++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and value is = " + i);

            condition.signal();         
            condition.await();

        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need at least 2 runnables (tasks) so that the executor can run them using different threads. Additionally you need some means of communication between the tasks (or let them spawn new subtasks) in order to get the behavior you want. However, I strongly suggest you dig somewhat deeper into threading and tasks. Having 2 threads running a basically similar task sequentially kind of defies the purpose of multithreading - just as binding tasks to specific threads would kind of defy the purpose of thread pools.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.

If "Having 2 threads running a basically similar task sequentially kind of defies the purpose of multithreading" .... then what is the use of Executor.newFixedThreadPool() and then .execute(runnable) methods ?

Aren't we just executing the same runnable via different threads?

Comment: `Executor.newFixedThreadPool()` is meant to provide a fixed pool of worker threads, any of which can be handed a task that needs execution. Via `Executor.execute(Runnable)` you pass a single task to the executor which then hands that task to a worker thread. The basic idea is that one task is executed by one thread.

Answer (score 3):

Made some changes in your program. Run it and check if it solves the confusion.

```
public class LocksPackagePractice {
    private int i = 0;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    Runnable r = () -> {
        printValue();
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LocksPackagePractice().trigger();
    }
    void trigger() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        service.submit(r);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            service.execute(r);
        }
    }
    void printValue() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            i++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and value is = " + i);
            condition.signal();
            condition.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you following output

```
pool-1-thread-1 and value is = 1
pool-1-thread-2 and value is = 2
pool-1-thread-1 and value is = 3
pool-1-thread-2 and value is = 4
pool-1-thread-1 and value is = 5
pool-1-thread-2 and value is = 6
```

Comment: Do you know why is this stuck at 6 ?

Comment: yes!! Executors have to be stopped explicitly - otherwise they keep listening for new tasks. You need to shutdown the executor using service.shutdown() method. I hope this helps.

Comment: Calling `shutdown()` wouldn’t help as all your task are hanging in `condition.await()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but do you need input to be ordered ? Because you use blocking operations (locks) and it is not good in case of performance.

This code :

```
private AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    ForTestApplication testApplication = new ForTestApplication();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      executor.execute(testApplication::print);
    }

  }

  public void print () {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + number.incrementAndGet());
  }
```

uses `AtomicInteger` instead of simple `int` value and lock operations. But order of output may be like this :

```
pool-1-thread-1 : 1
pool-1-thread-2 : 2
pool-1-thread-1 : 3
pool-1-thread-1 : 4
pool-1-thread-2 : 5
pool-1-thread-2 : 7
pool-1-thread-1 : 6
pool-1-thread-2 : 8
pool-1-thread-1 : 9
pool-1-thread-2 : 10
```

It you need order in your output then need to think how to deal with it.